# Can not use group by function

Tags: sql

Data on Table:-

```
wkt     Partners                Team            Opponent        Runs   Balls
1       S Hope & E Lewis        WEST INDIES     SOUTH AFRICA    43     66
2       S Hope & S Hetmyer      WEST INDIES     SOUTH AFRICA    70     79
3       D Bravo & S Hetmyer     WEST INDIES     SOUTH AFRICA    84     97

1       J Malan & Q Kock        SOUTH AFRICA    WEST INDIES     3      4
2       J Malan & F Plessis     SOUTH AFRICA    WEST INDIES     32     44
3       J Malan & R Dussen      SOUTH AFRICA    WEST INDIES     100    90

1       S Dhawan & R Sharma     INDIA           IRELAND         3      8
2       V Kohli & R Sharma      INDIA           IRELAND         102    70
```

I want to return the pair of partners, team they belong to, opponent they play against only once for each wkt where runs are highest for that particular wkt

For above table I'd like result as follow

```
wkt     Partners                Team            Opponent        Runs   Balls
1       S Hope & E Lewis        WEST INDIES     SOUTH AFRICA    43     66
2       V Kohli & R Sharma      INDIA           IRELAND         102    70
3       J Malan & R Dussen      SOUTH AFRICA    WEST INDIES     100    90
```

Following is the code that I've used

```
SELECT wkt, Partners, Team, Opponent, max(Runs), Balls
FROM Partnerships
GROUP BY wkt
```

But I've been stuck with following error

```
Column 'Partnerships.Partners' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `row_number()`?

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by wkt order by runs desc) as seqnum
      from Partnerships p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you very much.